# How do I make NSSortDescriptor for Array Work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I managed to create an `Array` of `MyLocation` objects with their distance property set in the first of 2 tabs in a `tabBarController`.  In my 2nd tab I get it like so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self setAnnotationsToSort:myDelegate.annotationsToSort];
```

and right after this line I call this method:

```
-(void)sort{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [self.annotationsToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

which should sort my `Array`.  However my `tableView` currently loads with the unsorted version of the `Array`, `self.annotationsToSort`.  How do I reload the `tableView` but force it to use the new `sortedArray`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything with `sortedArray`. Try

```
self.annotationsToSort = [self.annotationsToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: yeah i tried that but appartently the method sortedArrayUsingDescriptors returns an NSArray and my self.annotationsToSort is NSMutableArray

Comment: Just make it a `mutableCopy` so you can store it as a `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 2):

Call:

`self.annotationsToSort = sortedArray;`

Before you call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this step:

```
self.annotationsToSort = [(NSArray*)sortedArray mutableCopy];
```

thanks guys